# Can't connect to SQL Server database from UWP

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, uwp

I have a UWP C# app and I need to connect to my SQL Server Express database.

When I connect to the database from tools option in Visual Studio, I can copy the connection string. Connectivity tests successfully, but when I try to connect with code I always get this error:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

```
    string connectionString =
         @"Data Source=DESKTOP-IF672GA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sc.Open();
```

Comment: Random thought is it missing the `;` at the end?

Comment: I added now but it doesnt work still

Comment: Have you got the sql server Agent service running in services.msc?

Comment: Just to clarify, SQL Server Management Studio is a client tool used to connect to SQL Server and work with your server instance and databases.  It is not the database server itself.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio to debug issue.  First check login window.  It should show Windows Credentials (in connection string integrated security)  and the same server : "DESKTOP-IF672GA\SQLEXPRESS".  Then try to complete login.  Check under databases in explorer that the database TestDatabase is attached.  Next do a simple query in SSMS to verify you have proper credentials to read database.

Comment: I'm tryint to run agent service but it is saying that it was automatically stopped when I start it

Comment: SQL Server Express does not include the SQL Agent service.

Comment: That is not good then. The event log should tell you  more.

Comment: If you build that code in a console app (so not in UWP), does it work then? is "DESKTOP-IF672GA" your machine? Can you replace it with . (so the data source becomes `.\SQLEXPRESS` )

Comment: I used this connection string now  @"Data Source = DESKTOP - IF672GA\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = GameGuessing; Integrated Security = true;"; and it is throwing "System.Exception: 'Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.'" but broswer is started in services

Comment: In console app same connection string works. without that spaces between desktop and IF672GA that is mistype

Comment: I need to get it working in UWP but it just doesn't work. I even tried enabling TCP/IP but it didnt help. **EDIT Enablind TCP/IP helped. I just didnt restart service

Comment: Has your question been solved? Do you have any progress?

Comment: Enabling TPC/IP in SQL Server configuration manager helped. Nothing else

Comment: That’s great, I’m glad to hear your issue has been solved. You could turn your comment into an answer and mark yourself, which can help others that face same question.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling TPC/IP in SQL Server configuration manager helped.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup UWP sandboxing as a likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue when I use Windows authentication. Could you please try to use **SQL Server authentication** instead of Windows authentication?

As follows:

```
string connectionString =@"Data Source = DESKTOP-IF672GA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = TestDatabase;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxxx";
```

Answer (score 0):

enable Named Pipes, and TCP/IP.

1. Type compmgmt.msc in the CommandLine, to Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Enable Named Pipes, and TCP/IP.
3. restart SQL service and Server Browser.

[image]

[image]

If not work, Open the Package.appxmanifest file of your UWP project in the manifest designer. In the Capabilities tab, select the Enterprise Authentication checkbox if you are using Windows Authentication for authenticating your SQL Server. and following:

- privateNetworkClientServer
- enterpriseAuthentication
- internetClient
- internetClientServer

[image]

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases#first-set-up-your-solution